# XPath selector returning an empty list instead of targeted value

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some data from this table: https://sofifa.com/ but I ran into a problem when trying to extract information from the Value column. I've used Mozilla dev-tools to get the XPath selectors which worked fine for Names and Overall ratings, but in the case of Value, using the browser-generated XPath only returns an empty list. I'm using Scrapy.

```
In [85]: value = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[13]').extract()                                       
    
In [86]: value                                                                                                                               
Out[86]: []
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Can you include a sample of the HTML in the question, for posterity? If the link dies or is modified then the question will no longer make sense, and the answer will be invalidated.

Comment: Yes I will do it, but what should I do exactly? Am I supposed to just copy part of the HTML that is relevant to the question?

Comment: Yep, that would be good - whatever you think it representative of the problem. Questions are limited to 30KB in total, but I tend to think that is too large - make it manageable to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at page source you will find out player's values are under the `data-col="vl"` so you can extract it with XPath:

```py
response.xpath('//*[@data-col="vl"]/text()').extract()
```

Which give you all values in the table.

In order to crawl a page you better not using the XPath which inspect element gives you but use page source and try to find appropriate XPath statement by elements data and test it in `scrapy shell`.

Comment: Thank you Moein, this worked perfectly. I'm still learning and didn't realize there was someting wrong with using inspect element, but your way is much more readable and it seems more reliable as well. I'm gonna try to refactor my code to make use of such simpler statements.